# iOS keychain:strange behavior while setting and getting data in/out the keychain

Tags: ios, objective-c, wrapper, keychain

All this happened in my simulator.
While practicing using keychain wrappers I've found myself in a strange situation. I was trying to learn how to insert and retrieve data form the keychain, and, in order to do this, I started a new project in which, the only thing I did, was writing in the **"(void)viewDidLoad"** method of my **ViewController** a default **username**, a default **password**, storing and trying to retrieve them on a second run of my Application.

This should have been a piece of cake but I've found out that my application was crashing. This is the code I used:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

[super viewDidLoad];

//Keychain wrapper definition
KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"YourAppLogin" accessGroup:nil];

//Getting DATA:
NSLog(@"Retrieving User DATA");
password = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
username = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
NSLog(@"pwd = %@",password);
NSLog(@"user = %@",username);

//Setting DATA:
[keychainItem setObject:@"password you are saving" forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
[keychainItem setObject:@"username you are saving" forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];  
}
```

Xcode was giving me an **NSInternalInconsistencyException** uncaught.
Playing around with the code I realized that the problem occurred only when setting a new password (at the first run of my App or after a reset of the keychain) and, **here comes the strange part**, only if I set my password before the username. So rewriting the code swapping the

```
//Setting DATA
[keychainItem setObject:@"username you are saving" forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
[keychainItem setObject:@"password you are saving" forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];     
}
```

solved my problem. Can anybody explain me why?

Finally I would like to ask if retrieving my **password** in a second run of my application will result in a encrypted version of it. This because i tried to get my password in 2 ways:

1) I got it right after storing it

```
//saving DATA
[keychainItem setObject:@"username you are saving" forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
[keychainItem setObject:@"password you are saving" forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];

//getting DATA:
username = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
password = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
NSLog(@"\nUser: %@ \nPassword: %@",username,password);
```

the result was

```
User: username you are saving
Password: password you are saving
```

2)I got my password in a second run putting the setting part under comment

```
//saving DATA
//[keychainItem setObject:@"username you are saving" forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
//[keychainItem setObject:@"password you are saving" forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];

//getting DATA:
username = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
password = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
NSLog(@"\nUser: %@ \nPassword: %@",username,password);
```

the result was

```
User: username you are saving
Password: <70617373 776f7264 20796f75 20617265 20736176 696e67>
```

So is this a **encrypted** version of my **password** or what???

Thank you

Comment: It's not encrypted. The numbers are just the hex values of the string "password you are saving". What do you get if you print the value of `[password class]` in this case - maybe it's `NSData` and not `NSString`.

Comment: I now tried and `[password class]` resulted as: __NSCFData so you were right. I solved my problem using a `NSData *p = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];` then `password = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:p encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't understood why putting in the Keychain the **password** before the **username** makes the app crash, but I learned that, in order to get the **password** back from the **keychain** you have to store it first in a **NSData**, you should do so:

```
NSData *pwd = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)]; 
password =    [[NSString alloc] initWithData:pwd encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```